# Locked out of my phone!

Tags: password

I'm locked out of my phone and I need to change the password on it how do I reset it and clearing everything off my phone?

Comment: Use Android device manager

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use [recovery mode](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/use-recovery-mode-android/) to perform a wipe and factory reset.